# What is the meaning of the sentence "すごかないわよ"?

Tags: meaning

Does すご refer to すごく or すごい?

Dictionaries have no entries on すごかない. I understand that わよ are sentence ending particles though.

Comment: Welcome to stackexchange! Right now, this question might be a bit hard to answer without context -- it could be a typo, slang, or something else. It would help if you could you add where you found this, and if it was part of some larger sentence.

Comment: @blutorange No context needed; It is a complete sentence.  It is 100% grammatical as well.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 「すご**か**ないわよ」＝「すご**くは**ないわよ」= "It is not that great/awesome."

「か」 is a colloquial contraction of 「くは」, with 「く」 being the last syllable of the [連用形]{れんようけい}= "continuative form"  of an i-adjective (「すごい」 in this case.  「すごく」 is the 連用形.) and 「は」 being a topic marker.

This 「か」 is mostly, if not exclusively, heard around Tokyo.

Other examples:

「うま**か**ねえ」＜「うま**くは**ない」 "It ain't yummy." (Kanto tough guy speech)

「[高]{たか}**か**ないけど・・」＜「高**くは**ないけど・・」 "It is not expensive, but ..."